# How to setup sublime text 3 to run on C++11, but it opens the cmd each run?

Tags: c++11, sublimetext3, build-system

How do I run C++11 in Sublime Text 3?

I found this and this works, but I want it to be able to open cmd each run.

(1)

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
]
}
```

Like this one:
(2)

```
{ 
    "cmd":
     [
         "g++", "-Wall", "-ansi", "-pedantic-errors", "$file_name", "-o", 
         "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", 
         "cmd", "/k" , "$file_base_name"
    ], 
     "selector": "source.cpp", 
     "working_dir": "${file_path}", 
     "shell": true 
}
```

The problem with (1) is it runs with the console inside Sublime Text 3, I don't want that, unfortunately.
The problem with (2) is it runs well and it opens CMD each time, which is what I need, but it's on C++98. When I need C++11.

So, is there a way to modify any one of these build systems so that I can run C++11 and make it open CMD every run (instead of running it on the console)? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the version that runs in `cmd` like you want to use the correct compiler arguments to get the version you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with a little bit of tinkering involved.

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && start cmd /k \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
]
}
```